# How to get return value from Dialog in Android

Tags: c#, android, android-layout, android-fragments, dialog

I am a very new in Android(c#)

I would like to ask anyone who can help me, it will appreciate.

I need to call a dialog which I can choose any number (1-9) from this dialog then it will close the dialog then return a value for me as a sample below.

```
private void removeItem
{
    ....
    int qty = ShowDialog();// method to show dialog then return value
    ....
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Uhm.. you know Android is Java, not C#, right?

Comment: He might be using MonoDroid...

Answer (score 0):

Generally you create a Bundle to share the information, so the paradigm is a little different. So if you Google say "android return value from dialog" you can find a lot of stuff that will help you already on stackoverflow. "android bundle" will take you directly to the Android documentation.  On the other hand, one reason I have no reputation here is I always found my answers here before asking a question..

Comment: You can also earn rep by answering and helping in here, so congratulations on your first shot!